# render :layout with rss

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rss

I am running into render :layout being ignored in a respond_to block. I am trying to create an rss feed. If I change the format to xml and remove the

```
  xml.rss :version => "2.0" do
```

from the builder, all works just fine and I get an xml file. However, adding that back in and putting this in my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :layout => 'application' }
    format.rss  { render :layout => false } 
end
```

I get a missing template error:

```
Missing template organizations/home/show, application/show with {:handlers=>[:erg,
:builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:rss], :locale=>[:en, :en]}.
```

Rendering the html version of the page works just fine (also works if tell it :layout false and it will work correctly and not render a layout)

Thoughts?